# StreamWriter - Not appending to created file

Tags: c#, file-io, streamwriter

I am using the StreamWriter object to write to either a file that is created by the constructor or already exists. If the file exists then it appends data. If not, then it should create a file and then also append data. The problem is that when the file needs to be created, the StreamWriter constructor creates the file but does not write any data to the file.

```
bool fileExists = File.Exists(filePath);

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
    if (!fileExists)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("start");
    }

    writer.WriteLine("data");
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers. The using block takes care of closing the writer. As for other people saying it works for them, is there any information I can give you to further diagnose the problem? The file is localed across a network. Could that be a potential problem. Intermittently I receive the errors, "Could not find a part of the path ..." and "The specified network name is no longer available."

Comment: your code works perfectly fine on my machine.

Comment: Works for me too... @Dan, try again and check, maybe you missed something on the first run? the using statement should be taking care of closing and flushing...

Comment: Your code snippet above works a treat for me, are you sure something else isn't interfering with the file?

Comment: I checked my code again and still don't see anything out of the ordinary. The weird thing about all this is that it will work if the file exists. I'll receive a file with contents "data data data". But it never appends anything on the initial call.

Comment: Are you calling this method from multiple concurrent threads?

Comment: By any chance is this code wrapped in a try...catch block with no error handling in the catch statement?

Comment: You could write what filePath you are using, check if you have appropriate rights to create files on remote machine.

Comment: It is not wrapped in a try catch. I included the Exceptions in the EDIT block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I figured it out. My local machine was having problems intermittently accessing the file over the network. I uploaded the code to the server and ran it there without any problems. I really appreciate all the help. I'm sorry the solution wasn't very exciting.

Answer (score 2):

The code ran fine on my computer. Can we know what the variable filePath contains? Perhaps you were looking at the wrong file...

UPDATE: Network problem? Maybe someone was doing something on the other side of the network. Try writing to a local file. If it works, try writing to a remote file on another location.

Comment: string filePath = @"\\server\folder\filename.htm";
It works on subsequent calls, after the file is created so I know it is the right path.

Comment: Based on the intermittent error messages you gave, the server itself could be busy/offline. Or the folder itself was deleted, and you don't have permission to create the folder (or haven't created the folder). A file/folder permission issue perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, after 3 runs I've:

```
start
data
data
data
```

Are you sure, that your not trying access file, that for some reason you can't write to it? Also, just to make sure, place `writer.Close()` before disposing it, although `Dispose()` should flush the data. If this won't help, try to create the file manually using `File.Create()` with appropriate flags.

//Edit:
I've tried this code on my machine:

```
public unsafe static void Main()
{
    string filePath = @"\\COMP-NAME\Documents\foo.txt";
    FileStream fs = null;
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        fs = File.Create(filePath);
    else
        fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Append);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("data");
    }
}
```

And it runs smoothly, could try this one?

Comment: That was my first reaction. I tried creating the file if it didn't exist and just using the above code, but that also would write on the first call. Are there any latency issues with creating a file on a server this way?

Comment: I've posted code that I've cooked to check if this will work over network, under Edit section. Don't treat it as a production code btw, cause of not 100% correct usage of using this time, but it works for me, it's putting data when creating file and then appending to id.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked correctly for me..

Try a using statement

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
    if (!fileExists)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("start");
    }

    writer.WriteLine("data");
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Comment: The author is using `using` statement?

Comment: If you look at the sample code, I am using a using statement?

Answer (score 0):

Could try the [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx) function.  There is a good example at the bottom and list of the [FileModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx)
FileMode.Append is what you would want

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to others who have posted, your code is working fine on my PC.

It might help for you to break your code in two parts, the first part writing the header if the file doesn't already exist, then the second part writing the data:

```
try
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("start");
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
}

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
    writer.WriteLine("data");
}
```